# Install-ADDSDomainController Credential Error 12

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm, domaincontroller

Hello,

I am trying to automate the installation and promotion of domain controllers, which are being added to an existing root forest with no child domains. I'm using the following code to perform this action during a ConfigMgr Task Sequence (so the script itself is being run as System):

```
function Install-DomainController
{
    param(
        [string]$CUST_DSRMPassword,
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$CUST_ADDSCredentials
    )

    Write-LogEntry -Type Information -Message "Promoting the Server to a Domain Controller..."

    try
    {
        Install-ADDSDomainController `
        -NoGlobalCatalog:$false `
        -CreateDNSDelegation:$false `
        -CriticalReplicationOnly:$false `
        -Credential $CUST_ADDSCredentials `
        -Adprepcredential $CUST_ADDSCredentials `
        -DatabasePath "$NTDSPath" `
        -DomainName "$DomainName" `
        -InstallDNS:$true `
        -LogPath "$NTDSPath" `
        -ReplicationSourceDC "$CUST_DomainControllerToUse" `
        -SysvolPath "$SysvolPath" `
        -Force:$true `
        -NoRebootOnCompletion:$true `
        -SafeModeAdministratorPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $CUST_DSRMPassword -Force)
     }
    catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName

        Write-LogEntry -Type Error -Message "The Item '$FailedItem' caused the following error: '$ErrorMessage'!"
    }
}
```

The credentials are being passed as a parameter formatted as [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]. I can verify the credentials are correct by opening a cmd window, running powershell and using the following code during runtime:

```
$CUST_ADDSCredentials.Password
$CUST_ADDSCredentials.GetNetworkCredential()
$CUST_ADDSCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

And I know the user I'm passing on to the cmdlet is infact a member of the domain admins, enterprise admins and schema admins. Yet I still recieve the following error message:

> User is not DA or EA. VerifyUserCredentialPermissions error message:
>   You have not supplied user credentials that belong to the Domain
>   Admins group or the Enterprise Admins group. The installation may fail
>   with an access denied error. Do you want to continue?

I'm puzzled as to what I'm doing wrong here. Would I perhaps be required to run the cmdlet in a different context by opening a seperate PSSession and using Invoke-Command -Session -ScriptBlock{}? Or is there perhaps something obvious I'm missing?

Thankful for any help :-)

Best Regards,

Fred

Comment: Check if supplying `-SkipPreChecks` parameter per manual would make it work. If not, gather the error and debug from there. Maybe you've got Kerberos errors that prevent validating your supplied credentials.

Comment: Thank you Vesper - I'll do that and post the results here.

Comment: I'm afraid the outcome is the same even when using the above parameter to skip the prechecks. I'll continue troubleshooting and will post results here, when I have them - could be end of the week though.

Comment: try by adding the user only in domain Admin group

Comment: Adding the user to only one of the groups did not change anything either. I tried creating a New-PSSession and running the Install-ADDSDomainController cmdlet in the session via Invoke-Command -Session -ScriptBlock {}. This at least results in a pop-up showing, requiring me to enter credentials (even though I've passed them to the Session and the ScriptBlock?) but when trying to enter anything, the mouse gets stuck on the pop-up and I can't get into the fileds, tabbing doesn't anything either. I'll experiment further...

Comment: Given up on this. I'm guessing at this point, that for some reason, SCCM does not allow a proper session to be opened, thus the credentials cannot be properly checked. The script works outside of a Task Sequence just fine, even when running it as System and passing domain admin creds to it. Promo will be done manually.